# Restarting a freeglut / OpenGL C application fails on Ubuntu when using special cursors

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu, x11, freeglut

I have a freeglut application that can be closed and reopened on user demand. It works fine on Windows and Ubuntu, unless I specify the Mouse cursor look. Here's a minimum working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void keyboard(unsigned char key, const int x, const int y);
void display(void);
void closeme(void);
void init_main(int argc, char **argv);

int win_main_no = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    init_main(argc, argv);
    printf("'%s': passed line %i\n", __func__, __LINE__);

    sleep(1);

    init_main(argc, argv);
    printf("'%s': passed line %i\n", __func__, __LINE__);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void init_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Test");

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_CROSSHAIR); /**< this is the problem */

    glClearColor(0., 0., 0., 0.);
    glClearDepth(1.);

    win_main_no = glutGetWindow();

    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutCloseFunc(closeme);
    glutMainLoop();
}

void closeme(void)
{
    printf("'%s': passed line %i\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    glutDestroyWindow(win_main_no);
    glutLeaveMainLoop();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, const int x, const int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
        case 27:
        printf("'%s': passed line %i\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        glutLeaveMainLoop();
        printf("'%s': passed line %i\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        break;
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-5, 5, -5, 5, -2, 2);

    glColor3f(1., 0., 0.);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2d(-.5, .5);
        glVertex2d(-.5, -.5);
        glVertex2d(.5, -.5);
        glVertex2d(.5, .5);
    glEnd();

    glRasterPos3d(1.05, 0., 0.);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, 'x');
    glRasterPos3d(0., 0., 1.05);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, 'y');
    glRasterPos3d(0., 1.05, 0.);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, 'z');

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

You can make it via

```
gcc -O0 -g -Wall -std=c99 -o test test.c -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

or (Linux)

```
gcc -O0 -g -Wall -std=c99 -o test test.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

On WINDOWS 7 64 bit, freeglut 2.8.0, the output reads

```
'keyboard': passed line 61
'keyboard': passed line 63
'closeme': passed line 51
'main': passed line 15
'keyboard': passed line 61
'keyboard': passed line 63
'closeme': passed line 51
'main': passed line 20
```

But on UBUNTU 64 bit 14.04, freeglut from repository:

```
'keyboard': passed line 61
'keyboard': passed line 63
'closeme': passed line 51
'main': passed line 15
X Error of failed request:  BadCursor (invalid Cursor parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x460000a
  Serial number of failed request:  64
  Current serial number in output stream:  67
'closeme': passed line 51
```

Is there a way to prevent from this (except a flag that tells to not use the cursor on Linux)? This message "invalid Cursor parameter" puzzles me, as the same flag has worked on the first run. Is there a need to reset this somehow when closing the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in freeglut.

Download the source, look at `freeglut_cursor.c` , wonder who cleans up the cursor cache when the X11 display is closed. The answer is, sadly, no one.

You can easily fix it yourself and optionally submit a patch to freeglut maintainers, or just file a bug to them.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, svn rev 1749. The X error was due to re-using a stale cached Cursor left from the previous connection to the X server.

Btw, there's also a bug tracker on sourceforge where you can submit bugs: https://sourceforge.net/p/freeglut/bugs/

A combination of submitting a bug to the tracker, and sending an email to the freeglut-developer mailing list with the bug number/url, is probably best if the bug is urgent.

Cheers.